# wpf trigger setter issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I am trying to add a Trigger to a control template (for a button) and I am getting an error that says the target cannot be found. Here is a code snippet

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
 <Border x:Name="t"
         Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
         <Border.Background>
             <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                  EndPoint="0,1">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                     <GradientStop x:Name="BackgroundGradientStop1"
                                   Offset="0"
                                   Color="{StaticResource BackgroundColor1}" />
                     <GradientStop x:Name="BackgroundGradientStop2"
                                   Offset="1"
                                   Color="{StaticResource BackgroundColor2}" />
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>

        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
  </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="False">
               <Setter TargetName="BackgroundGradientStop1"
                       Property="Color"
                       Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
```

The name "BackgroundGradientStop1" in the Setter of the Trigger is reported as not found, however it is defined before that in the code just above. The same target name is used in MultiTriggers after this one and no error is reported.

What is wrong with my code?
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain (only because I can't find MSDN backing documentation) this is because the `GradientStop` is not a `FrameworkElement`.  You should only be able to target `FrameworkElement`'s in Setters. The solution for what you're trying to accomplish is probably to define multiple `LinearGradientBrush`'s as resources, and use the trigger to set the Background property of the Border element in your `ControlTemplate` triggers to one of those resources.